# jQuery: How to get text and set to attribute in <a>?

Tags: jquery

Below HTML & JS - Need to get a tag text and set to "tabName"

I can able to get text on click. But, in "TabName" it insert as empty.

Not sure which logic is missing

**HTML:**

```
    <ul class="custom-tabs-item">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a data-toggle="tab" href="#dashboard" class="nav-link">Dashboard</a>
        </li> 
        <li class="nav-item custom-tabs-link">
            <a data-toggle="tab" href="#bookings" class="nav-link ">Bookings</a>
        </li> 
    </ul>
```

**JS:**

```
    let getTabContentLink = $('.custom-tabs-container li.nav-item a');
    let tabContentTxt = '';
    getTabContentLink.on('click', function(){
        tabContentTxt = $(this).text();
    });
    let accountTabLayer = {
      event: {
        eventInfo: {
          tabName: tabContentTxt
        }
      }
    };
    DTM.setDataLayer(accountTabLayer);
```

Comment: Shouldn't the `dataLayer` call be *inside* the event handler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `let accountTabLayer` code is probably running before your actual callback. Can you put that stuff inside your click callback?

```
getTabContentLink.on('click', function(){
    const tabContentTxt = $(this).text();
    const accountTabLayer = {
      event: {
        eventInfo: {
          tabName: tabContentTxt
        }
      }
   };

   DTM.setDataLayer(accountTabLayer);
});
```